# Blocking DNS server from a router via iptables

Tags: router, dns, iptables

I'm trying to block google dns server (*8.8.8.8*) from my router, so no machine in the network could not access this dns server.

here is my `iptables` table:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             dns.google
DROP       all  --  dns.google           anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             dns.google
DROP       all  --  dns.google           anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             dns.google
DROP       all  --  dns.google           anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I'm new to `iptables`,
first I added `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` rules, which didn't do anything.
Then `FORWARD` worked when pinging (i guess because the router forwards the request to the internet?):

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

there is no ping from *8.8.8.8*.
however it is still possible to use *8.8.8.8* as a dns server:

```
$ nslookup superuser.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   superuser.com
Address: 104.18.43.79
Name:   superuser.com
Address: 172.64.144.177
```

What is the problem?
Also I still can't figure out difference between `source` and `destination` in each chain (If machine on the network initiate a connection to *8.8.8.8* for example the router see *8.8.8.8* as destination and when the router receive response from *8.8.8.8* it sees *8.8.8.8* as source?)

Thanks.

Comment: Try posting the output of `iptables-save`

Comment: Are you able to block the Google DNS if you follow instructions from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14649005/1997776?